# What is the best word to describe business travel?

Tags: business-language

If my company sent me to another city to carry out some duties for the company there and return after a while (e.g., 1 week or less), then what is the best word to describe this business travel? Can I call it "mission"?

Comment: A business trip, I would say.

Comment: It depends on the company and country.  I have been in some who would call it a trip and others (with a more continental European culture) a mission

Comment: With all the quarantine measures currently, perhaps *holiday* or *retreat*. But *business trip* is the generic term you’re seeking.

Comment: We don't use 'travel' in this way as a countable noun.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good catch. So can I say "a business trip"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think word mission would be more apt for describing the task for the trip, the term business trip would be more appropriate to explain the trip in general
Ex: I am going to Mali for a business trip, the mission this time is to finalize the details regarding the consignment.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This would benefit from defining your terms with research.  Please take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] for more information on how to answer, and thanks.